# SFDX ORG shape with PROD metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

Our company PROD ORG is a big monolithic application with heavy tangled apex code and metadata. We are about to introduce some more apps in the near future and I personally wanted to follow the modular development with the use of SFDX with unlocked packages and with SOC and DI patterns by Andrew Fawcett. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MY2_AfjtBp8) is the youtube video

Now the issues are

1. Since we have very tight time lines, we wanted to introduce new apps by following the above design patterns.
2. But since we need some features to be used from current monolithic application, we don't want to touch the existing ORG and reuse the same monolithic application because of timelines.
3. I came to know about the ORG Shape, will it give the shape of the PROD including all the metadata like Apex classes, workflows..etc?
4. If it gives the whole ORG shape, then how much time would it take to spin up such scratch ORG? We also wanted to use SFDX for CI/CD with these scratch ORG's.

Comment: Org Shape is still in Pilot and that you will need to reach out to Salesforce to participate in that Pilot. There's a dedicated community for this topic which can help you on questions around it. You will need to ask questions around this topic on [this group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000009TPk) once you have participated in the pilot.